# How to remove previous data on the user's phone after releasing new version?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to update my app but I want to be sure that there will not remain anything on user's phone from previous version.

While developing, When we `Rebuild` the project, previous data on the device gets removed, I want to something like this happen in real after releasing to the store.

I don't like to check for cleaning old data, every time the user runs the app.

How to remove previous version of the app and fully install new version on the user's phone?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any event fired when you app is installed or launched for the first time.

So if you are storing your data as IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings, the best option would be to store the app version in the ApplicationSettings and clear use IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Clear(); the first time you notice an outdated version.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You can simply wipe all isolated storage settings if that is required, or you can simply check a specific setting at launch (e.g. check if a stored setting called 'v1.5' exists) and then do whatever you need to do for the new version.